# Django working under IIS7

Tags: django, iis, iis-7

has someone a detailed description (if any) of a working installation of Django on Windows under IIS7? Already looked at PyISAPIe, etc. (and relative sites, groups, forums) but all description are somewhat inaccurate and until now I've been unsuccesful. The apparently fastest solution(PyISAPIe) seems to have some bugs as from their google group home page.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the newest release of PyISAPIe, there's an example Django setup with WSGI in there.